# Table cell-only sorting in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix

I need to place cells of every 2nd and 3rd column in sorted order. Thus, I need to swap X[N][2] and X[N][3] if X[N][2] > X[N][3], where X - matrix, N - any natural number
I have a table file like this:

```
A 9 1 2
B 8 7 F
C 2 4 X
D 3 1 1
```

I need to get this:

```
A 1 9 2
B 7 8 F
C 2 4 X
D 1 3 1
```

So line order remained the same, but some cells X[i][2] and X[i][3] got swapped.

I thought about using pipeline with **xargs** **cut** and **sort** but it doesn't seem to be a good idea. Any suggestions where to dig?

Comment: not sure what the `cells`, `matrix` and `table file` is about ... looks like a flat file with lines and columns ... what am I missing?  you've mentioned `xargs`, `cut` and `sort` ... please post the code written so far; assuming this **is** just a flat file and you want to swap/order columns 2 and 3, I'd probably look at using `awk` (also take a look at `awk's ternary` operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with a small awk script:

```
# Swap X[N][2] and X[N][3] if X[N][2] > X[N][3]
$2 > $3 {
  tmp = $3
  $3 = $2
  $2 = tmp
}

# Print row
1
```

To use it in a script or shell as a one-liner: `awk '$2 > $3 { tmp = $3; $3 = $2; $2 = tmp } 1' inputfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2 > $3 {  temp3=$3;$3=$2;$2=temp3 }1' file
```

Using awk. If the second space delimited field is greater than the third, set a temporary variable (temp3) to the third space delimited field, set the 3rd field to the second and the second to the temporary variable. Print all lines with short hand 1